# How to change value by selected drop down value in - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Hay guys. In my angular project have product page. So in this part may be some product can have multiple product types,
for example :

ProductId-1 **TypeId-1** Price-$10

ProductId-1 **TypeId-2** Price-$15

ProductId-1 **TypeId-3** Price-$25

So in that case i will show types are in drop down box. So i want to change price by selecting drop down type value, So i want to get that selected TypeId and Price to component.ts for send to web api. can you help me.

Angular-7 Cli

### Product.component.html

```
<h5 class="product-price">**I WANT TO SHOW HERE DROP-DOWN SELECTED VALUE PRICE**</h5>

<h5>Select Type</h5>
<select
   [(ngModel)]="selectedType" > 
   <option 
       *ngFor="let type of productType" 
       [ngValue]="type.id">
        {{type.name}}
   </option>
 </select>
```

### Product.component.ts

```
 selectedType: { id: any; name:any ; price:any };

 productType:Array<Object> = [
  {id: 1, name: "100 ml", price:2000},
  {id: 2, name: "200 ml", price:4000},
  {id: 3, name: "300 ml", price:3000}
 ];
```

Comment: You haven't explained what isn't working.

Comment: I did not know how to show that price in here by changing drop-down value.

Comment: `<h5>{{selectedType.price}}</h5>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ngValue` property value as the object and then you can get the price from the model variable.

```
<h5 class="product-price">{{selectedType?.price}}</h5>

<h5>Select Type</h5>
<select
   [(ngModel)]="selectedType" > 
   <option 
       *ngFor="let type of productType" 
       [ngValue]="type">
        {{type.name}}
   </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: oh woow it's work.. how can i get that price and selected value to component.ts

Comment: @ThevinMalaka. :  you can access using `this.selectedType`